# Asyncio consumer from producer thread not working

Tags: python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have 2 main threads (consumer/producer) communicating via a `SimpleQueue`. I want the consumers to execute as fast as something is added to the queue. I also want to avoid `asyncio.Queue` since I want to keep consumer and producer decoupled and flexible for future changes.

I started looking in gevent, asyncio, etc. but it all feels very confusing to me.

```
from queue import SimpleQueue
from time import sleep
import threading

q = SimpleQueue()
q.put(1)
q.put(2)
q.put(3)


def serve_forever():
    import asyncio
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    while True:
        task = q.get()
        print(f"Dequeued task {task}")
        async def run_task():
            print(f"Working on task {task}")
        loop.create_task(run_task())  # run task


thread = threading.Thread(target=serve_forever)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
Dequeued task 1
Dequeued task 2
Dequeued task 3
```

Why doesn't `run_task` execute in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply calling `create_task` doesn't actually run anything; you need to have a running `asyncio` event loop, which you get by calling something like `asyncio.run` or `loop.run_until_complete`.

You don't need to create an explicit `loop` as you're doing, either; asyncio provides a default event loop.

Lastly, asyncio tasks won't run if you're never calling `await`, because this is how the current task yields execution time to other tasks. So even if we fix the earlier problems, your tasks will never execute because execution will be stuck inside your `while` loop. We need to be able to `await` on the `q.get()` calls, which isn't directly possible when using `queue.SimpleQueue`.

We can solve the above -- while still using `queue.SimpleQueue` -- by using the [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) method to run the non-async `q.get` calls (this runs the calls in a separate thread and allows us to asynchronously wait for the result). The following code works as I think you intended:

```py
import asyncio
import threading
import queue

q = queue.SimpleQueue()

q.put(1)
q.put(2)
q.put(3)


async def run_task(task):
    print(f"Working on task {task}")


async def serve_forever():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    while True:
        task = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: q.get())
        print(f"Dequeued task {task}")
        asyncio.create_task(run_task(task))  # run task


def thread_main():
    asyncio.run(serve_forever())


thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_main)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

# just hang around waiting for thread to exit (which it never will)
thread.join()
```

Output:

```
Dequeued task 1
Working on task 1
Dequeued task 2
Working on task 2
Dequeued task 3
Working on task 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually seems to work fine. Unfortunately I realised that for my real-life scenario problem each task is using a 3rd party blocking library so I think I can only try and see if I can use gevent/greenlets. Thanks anyway!